# How do I removeClass when I select specific option jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new with jQuery and after 1 day of searching google I still have no solution.
I need to remove `class="hidden"` when I select option with `value="test"` and add `class="hidden"` when I select another option without submit button. Please HELP.

```
<select name="cars" class="help">
    <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">audi</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden">
```

I tried:

```
$('.select option[value="test"]').clcik(function(){
    $(".hidden").removeClass();
});
```

And a lot of different stuff (give an id to option or some tag) but still nothing :(

Comment: You have a typo in `clcik` should be `click`

Comment: In future, please use a debugger, like `Firebug`, or the `Chrome developer tools` to look for errors in your console.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the selects change event, and check the value when it changes, as options generally don't fire mouse events.

```
$('.help').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'test') $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

to toggle the inputs class, do

```
$('.help').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').toggleClass('hidden', this.value != 'test');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHbaY/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.help').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'test')
     $(".hidden").removeClass();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(".help").change(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).val()) === "test"){
    $('input.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
if($(this).val()=="test")
  $(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax4UZ/)**

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.help').change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'test'){
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
$('.help').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'test') {$(input).removeClass('hidden');}
    else {$(input).addClass('hidden');}
})
```